# Can Java's XMLEncoder serialize objects that have non-serializable fields?

Tags: java, xml, serialization

I am really confused by all the opinions I find in books and even here so bear with me please!

It is stated in Clay Richardson's Professional Java JDK 6 that

> you will notice that MyBean does not implement Serializable. 
>   XMLEncoder/Decoder does not require classes it serializes to implement 
>   Serializable.

and that

> the XMLEncoder/Decoder API serializes object
>   instances without any knowledge of their private data members. It serializes based upon the object’s
>   methods, its JavaBean properties, exposed through the JavaBeans convention > of getters and setters (getXXX and setXXX).

Doesn't that mean that XMLEncoder can serialize non-serializable objects such as a `javafx.scence.color` if it is a field inside a JavaBean ? Well I tried to create a JavaBean and followed all the stated conventions about the naming and the default no-arg constructor as follows

```
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Map;

public class PCircle extends Shape implements Serializable {

    private Point2D position;
    private Map<String, Double> properties;
    private Color backColor;
    private Color strokeColor;

    public void setPosition(Point2D position) { this.position = position; }
    public Point2D getPosition() { return this.position; }


    public void setProperties(Map<String, Double> properties) { this.properties = properties; }
    public Map<String, Double> getProperties() { return this.properties; }


    public void setBackColor(Color color) { this.backColor = color; }
    public Color getBackColor() { return this.backColor; }

    public void setStrokeColor(Color color) { this.strokeColor = color; }
    public Color getStrokeColor() { return this.strokeColor; }

}
```

where `Shape` is an abstract class implementing `IShape` interface as shown below

```
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import java.util.Map;

public interface IShape {

    void setPosition(Point2D position);
    Point2D getPosition();

    void setProperties(Map<String, Double> properties);
    Map<String, Double> getProperties();

    void setBackColor(Color color);
    Color getBackColor();

    void setStrokeColor(Color color);
    Color getStrokeColor();

}

public abstract class Shape implements IShape {

    abstract public void setPosition(Point2D position);
    abstract public Point2D getPosition();


    abstract public void setProperties(Map<String, Double> properties);
    abstract public Map<String, Double> getProperties();

    abstract public void setBackColor(Color color);
    abstract public Color getBackColor();

    abstract public void setStrokeColor(Color color);
    abstract public Color getStrokeColor();

}
```

now if I run this main method to test

```
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import java.beans.XMLEncoder;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String, Double> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("First Property", 20.5);

        PCircle circle = new PCircle();

        circle.setPosition(new Point2D(20, 30));
        circle.setProperties(properties);
        circle.setBackColor(Color.BLACK);
        circle.setStrokeColor(Color.RED);

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("output.xml");
            XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(fos);
            encoder.writeObject(circle);
            encoder.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception! " + ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

I get this error

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: javafx.scene.paint.Color
Continuing ...
java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to evaluate: <unbound>=Class.new();
Continuing ...
java.lang.InstantiationException: javafx.scene.paint.Color
Continuing ...
java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to evaluate: <unbound>=Class.new();
Continuing ...
java.lang.InstantiationException: javafx.scene.paint.Color
Continuing ...
java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to evaluate: <unbound>=Class.new();
Continuing ...
java.lang.InstantiationException: javafx.scene.paint.Color
Continuing ...
java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to evaluate: <unbound>=Class.new();
Continuing ...
```

The interesting part is that if I use serializable classes such as `java.awt.Color`, the code works fine and the XML is generated. But how does that even matters even though it is stated clearly that the JavaBean is not required to implement the `Serializable` interface ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Doesn't that mean that `XMLEncoder` can serialize non-serializable objects such as a `javafx.scene.[paint.]color` if it is a field inside a JavaBean?

No. It means that it can serialize non-serializable objects such as a `javafx.scene.paint.color` *if they also observe the JavaBeans conventions*, and provided their object-valued attributes do likewise, and so on until closure.

In this case, `javafx.scene.paint.color` didn't have a no-args constructor. The fact that `java.awt.Color` worked was due to it observing the JavaBeans conventions, not to its being `Serializable`.

Comment: But doesn't that contradicts what the author said about serializing objects with no knowledge of their private fields ?

Comment: No. I don't understand why you ask.